# How can I check whether its parent view or subview when touch gesture event called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have two view. One is transparent view which contains subviews. I want to remove `screenView` only when parent view is clicked. I don't want to call tapGesture when i click `popUpView`. How to can check?

```
screenView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
screenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UITapGestureRecognizer * clearTable = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(clearTableViewAction:)];
[clearTable setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[screenView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[screenView addGestureRecognizer:clearTable];
screenView.tag = 100;
[self.view addSubview:screenView];

self.popUpView = [[UIView alloc]init];
self.popUpView.frame = ...
self.popUpView.backgroundColor = WhiteColor;
self.popUpView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.popUpView.tag = 200;
[screenView addSubview:self.popUpView];  

-(void)clearTableViewAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if(sender.view.tag == 100){
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{screenView.alpha = 0.0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [screenView removeFromSuperview];
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: If gave userInteractionEnabled as NO. Still TapGesture is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shouldReceiveTouch` delegate method and check:

Like,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    if ([touch.view.tag == 100) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        return NO; 
    }
}
```

Now, `clearTableViewAction` gesture method will not be called if you will click in `popUpView`.